# How can I increase plane shift's accuracy?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, spells, class-feature, planes, teleportation

Upon reading about the Harmonium Peacekeeper Prestige Class (*Dragon* #315, p47) whose 3rd level Planar Steed ability includes the ability to [plane shift](http://dndsrd.net/spellsPtoR.html#plane-shift) once per day from Arcadia to the first level of any nonevil plane, I decided to try to increase that plane-shift's accuracy.

My research has shown me precious little that does so:
[Accurate Jaunt](http://dndsrd.net/unearthedSpelltouchedFeats.html#accurate-jaunt) lets a character roll twice for teleportation effects, and cynosure (*Dragon* #338, p77), a 4th level Sorcerer/Wizard spell, reduces the distance from the target area by 75% (rounding fractional miles down).

Is there something easier or cheaper resource-wise than a 4th level spell or a feat of dubious utility that increases the accuracy of plane shift? My preference would be for the character to have as many Paladin levels as possible; *try* to leave out Full-casting classes like Cleric or Sorcerer/Wizard, if possible.

Comment: The goal is, I assume, to make *plane shift* more accurate *in general*, so, for example, making a Use Magic Device skill check to activate a *scroll of greater plane shift* [conj] (*Spell Compendium* 159) isn't an option? And, by extension, that employing methods other than *plane shift* for planar travel aren't acceptable workarounds either, correct?

Comment: Yeah, the goal is to make the ability work at better than avg 250mi inaccuracy. AJ improves things by 73mi each time it's used, on avg, and improves the average by 36.5mi. Obv the spell improves stuff by 75%, so by about 189mi to 63mi on avg. The spell is expensive, and the feat overpriced, IMO... And correct; PS is the goal, to utilize the ability to best effect.

Comment: That'd be great, but would only increase accuracy when the check succeeded; maximizing *that* would cost more resources (Stats or items) than just the *lesser amulet*. That it would be 100% accurate 30% of the time (for 10-11 Int) is great. Too bad PS doesn't work that way already.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So far as I'm aware, there's no better officialish spell than the 4th-level Sor/Wiz spell *cynosure* [div] (*Dragon* #308 77) for improving the accuracy of a [*plane shift*](http://dndsrd.net/spellsPtoR.html#plane-shift) effect, and there's no better officialish readily available feat than the spelltouched feat Accurate Jaunt (*Unearthed Arcana* 92) for improving the accuracy of a *plane shift* effect. I've a document that I think compiles *all* the Wizards of the Coast spells from the *Dungeons and Dragons, Third Edition* corpus that's [dnd-3.5e](/questions/tagged/dnd-3.5e) inclusive and another that similarly compiles *all* the feats. Those spells and feats are largely it for doing what you want to do.

There are likely other magic items than those below that may be helpful in improving a *plane shift* effect's accuracy, and I'll add those to this answer when I locate them, but I'm not immediately aware of any, and the research I *have* done has yielded no better results than those below. (I mean, seriously, I'm assuming *planar ring gates* (*Planar Handbook* 83) (200,000 gp; 20 lbs. ea.) and the *rope of crossing* (*PlH* 83-4) (90,000 gp; 10 lbs.), while interesting, just are *not* what you're looking for, nor is using an effect like the 8th-level Sor/Wiz spell *greater plane shift* [conj] (*Spell Compendium* 159), no matter if such an effect is created through an attuned gem, rune, scroll, staff, skull talisman, or spellworm.) The same goes for classes: I know of no class that improves a *plane shift* effect's accuracy. (But if I find one, I'll add it!)

#### Outliers and also-rans

- There's the poorly-named epic feat **Dark Transient** (Epic Insights Web column [“Epic Warlock Feats”](http://archive.wizards.com/default.asp?x=dnd/ei/20061027a)) that allows an epic warlock to

  > use *plane shift* with perfect accuracy (self and personal equipment only). You can also transport other creatures, but you then suffer the inaccuracies normally incurred when using this spell. Activating this ability requires a standard action.

  Obviously, taking the feat requires that the creature be an epic level warlock or that the DM approves a *very* generous reading of the slightly controversial term *bonus feat* (and most DM's don't).
- A creature that takes the feat **Touchstone** (*Sandstorm* 53) *et al.* can establish a link with the Great Orrery (*Planar Handbook* 178-9) on Mechanus. When the creature gains the touchstone site's higher-order ability, he can 3/recharge use an effect like the spell *plane shift* except that he's only off by 2d10+5 miles instead of 5d% miles.
- Although expensive, an ***amulet of the planes*** (*DMG* 247) (120,000 gp; 0 lbs.) is 100% accurate with a successful Intelligence check (DC 15). Far less expensive is the ***lesser amulet of the planes*** (*Dungeon* #107 69) (24,000 gp; 0 lbs.), which is identical to the original except it functions but 1/day. Note that only the DM stops an not-distracted, not-threatened creature from [taking 10 on ability checks](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/skills/usingSkills.htm#checksWithoutRolls).
- As an aside, creatures employing *plane shift* effects to reach the [**Seven Mounting Heavens of Celestia**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mount_Celestia) "always find themselves in the surf of an ocean surrounding Mount Celestia" on the plane's first layer, Lunia (*Manual of the Planes* 133-4). So at least where a traveler shows up on *that* plane is *somewhat* predictable. [Other planes apparently aren't nearly so accommodating.](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/34269/8610)

Comment: What's that *cynosure* spell do?

Comment: @GMJoe Much like the asker says, cast before a spell with a possibility of arriving off-target, *cynosure* reduces the off-target distance of the next spell by 75%. For example, if the caster would normally be 100 mi. off target, *cynosure*'s caster's 25 mi. off-target. Interestingly, *cynosure*'s usually cast on *another* creature (its range is touch and its target is one creature) as the spell's duration is only 1 round. (I guess modifying the spell with the feat Extend Spell is a possibility for a higher-level caster if the caster must use the spell on himself, though.)

Comment: *Safety* (SpC, 179) cast prior to *Plane Shift* "sends the subject of safety to a place of relative safety on that plane". So far that's all else I've found... I guess, 'you can't' is and answer too.

Comment: @Chemus Yeah, I thought about mentioning the spell *safety*, but didn't because, while it ensures… um… safety when using *plane shift*, the *safety* spell makes it sound like the caster no longer picks the *plane shift* spell's destination and, instead, only picks the plane.