# Where do you end up after returning from the Astral Plane?

Tags: dnd-5e, planes

Supposing a character ends up in the Astral Plane, according to the DMG you can find one of these pools which (if you find the right one) will return you to the Material Plane. But there isn't any detail on what place you return to. So, do you return to a random spot? Do you return to the place you left the Material Plane? Or are there one or more nexuses where beings will appear? For that matter, supposing you left from Toril, could you end up on, say, Eberron?

Answer (score 5):

## As a point of clarity, there is only one Material Plane in 5e.

The Player's Handbook clarifies with regards to the Planes of Existence:

> it encompasses every world where GMs run their adventures, all within the relatively mundane ... Material Plane

This implies that there is one plane wherein all the world's such as Eberron and Toril exist. There are no direct rules on how to travel between these world's but almost every planar spell is not limited with respect to a specific world as long as you have information regarding that world (i.e. a sigil sequence for a teleportation circle).

In conclusion, any planar magic that lets you specify a location can allow you to travel to any world in the Material Plane (as long as the Material Plane is a legal target). If the GM selects the location, they can choose in the same way.

Comment: aren't Eberron etc. different universes, which don't exist alongside each other?

Comment: @PixelMaster Not in 5th edition. All of them exist within the material plane. There are no rules regarding traveling between worlds. It is possible they are parallel realities but the plane encompasses them all.

Comment: Mike Mearls talked a little about it when dealing with Mindflayers on a DnDBeyond Youtube video. The worlds are like separate spheres in the same plane, Mindflayers used to be able to travel between them.

Comment: @Baergren That was based off of Spelljammer which is not yet canon in 5e

Comment: @DavidCoffron, perhaps not published in print yet, but this was a recently published video, just slightly prior to Xanathar's if I recall correctly so I would hold it as tentatively authoritative

Answer (score 3):

[This related topic](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/34269/where-does-a-traveler-arrive-when-a-planar-locations-unspecified?rq=1) explains about a similar question that touches the points that are relevant here.

You return wherever the DM wants. Technically, yes, you can leave Toril and end up in Eberron. However, as you said before, you found ***the right pool***, the subjectively right for you, is your own Material Plane, then you'll appear somewhere there where the GM put you unless your DM has a plan for it or is just a psycho (Who knows?), you should be back to your native plane.