# What is the difference between non-dimensional space and extra-dimensional space?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, planes

Can someone please explain to me the difference between non-dimensional space and extra-dimensional space in DnD 3.5?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

## The Terms *Extradimensional Space* and *Nondimensional Space* Are Interchangeable

This becomes clear when looking at how the terms are used in context. The most useful example is the [*portable hole*](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/magicItems/wondrousItems.htm#portableHole) (*DMG* 264) (20,000 gp; 0 lbs.), which says that it

> is a circle of cloth spun from the webs of a phase spider interwoven with strands of ether and beams of starlight. When opened fully, a *portable hole* is 6 feet in diameter, but it can be folded up to be as small as a pocket handkerchief. When spread upon any surface, it causes an **extradimensional space** 10 feet deep to come into being. This hole can be picked up from inside or out by simply taking hold of the edges of the cloth and folding it up. Either way, the entrance disappears, but anything inside the hole remains.
>
> The only air in the hole is that which enters when the hole is opened. It contains enough air to supply one Medium creature or two Small creatures for 10 minutes. (See Suffocation, page 304.) The cloth does not accumulate weight even if its hole is filled (with gold, for example). Each *portable hole* opens on its own particular **nondimensional space**. If a *bag of holding* (see page 248) is placed within a *portable hole*, a rift to the Astral Plane is torn in that place. Both the *bag* and the cloth are sucked into the void and forever lost. If a *portable hole* is placed within a *bag of holding*, it opens
>   a gate to the Astral Plane. The *hole*, the *bag*, and any creatures within a 10-foot radius are drawn there, the *portable hole* and *bag of holding* being destroyed in the process. (*DMG* 264)

Emphasis mine. Thus, even within the *portable hole*'s description, the terms *extradimensional space* and *nondimensional space* are used interchangeably. That's because such spaces are--no matter which term is used--technically [demiplanes](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/planes.htm#demiplanes):

> This catch-all category covers all extradimensional spaces that function like planes but have measurable size and limited access. Other kinds of planes are theoretically infinite
>   in size, but a demiplane might be only a few hundred feet across. Access to demiplanes may be limited to particular locations (such as a fixed gateway) or particular situations (such as a time of year or a weather condition). Some demiplanes are created by powerful
>   magic, some naturally evolve, and some appear according to the will of the deities.
>
> In the *D&D* cosmology, also known as the Great Wheel, the planes are connected in a specific fashion, as depicted in the diagram on page 153. (The diagram does not show demiplanes, because the location and even the existence of these extradimensional
>   spaces is constantly changing.) (*DMG* 147)

Therefore the extradimensional spaces of the [*bag of devouring*](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/magicItems/cursedItems.htm#bagofDevouring) (*DMG* 274) (n/a gp; 0 lbs.), the [*mirror of life-trapping*](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/magicItems/wondrousItems.htm#mirrorofLifeTrapping) (*DMG* 262) (2000,000 gp; 50 lbs.), the 2nd-level Sor/Wiz spell [*rope trick*](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/ropeTrick.htm) [trans] (*PH* 273), and the 7th-level Sor/Wiz spell *Mordenkainen's [magnificent mansion](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/magesMagnificentMansion.htm)* [conj] (*PH* 256) are the same kinds of spaces as the nondimensional spaces of the [*bag of holding*](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/magicItems/wondrousItems.htm#bagofHolding) (*DMG* 248) (2,500+ gp; 15+ lbs.), the pocket paradise created by the [*rod of security*](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/magicItems/rods.htm#security) (*DMG* 236) (61,000 gp; 5 lbs.), and the *[quiver of](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/magicItems/wondrousItems.htm#efficientQuiver) Ehlonna* (*DMG* 265) (1,800 gp; 2 lbs.).

**Speculation**
The *Player's Handbook* uses exclusively the term *extradimensional space*, while the *Dungeon Master's Guide* mixes the terms *extradimensional space* and *nondimensional space* freely. I think it was one of those things the authors never expected anyone to care about, hence not worth fixing... not expecting that over a decade after its release such term mixing would bother careful readers of their game.

Comment: Bag of Devouring was later revealed to be the limb/mouth of a living creature.

Comment: @nijineko Following the link: "The *bag* [*of devouring*] can hold up to 30 cubic feet of matter. It acts as a *bag of holding type I*, but each hour it has a 5% cumulative chance of swallowing the contents and then spitting the stuff out in some nonspace or on some other plane" (*DMG* 274).

Comment: Yes, I'm aware. Yet my statement is also accurate. It is in the descriptive text that it reveals it is actually a creature.

Comment: @nijineko I'm sorry, but is there a point that I should be making in this answer that I'm not? That seems to be *just* more information. I mean, the [*rod of security*](http://www.systemreferencedocuments.org/resources/systems/pennpaper/dnd35/soveliorsage/magicItemsPRR.html#rod-of-security) is more complicated than it appears here, too, but it, when you get down to it, is likewise just another extradimensional/nondimensional space. There's no reason so far as I can see to *detail* each instance.

Comment: The bag is uniquely the only living creature amongst all the examples given. As far as defining terms go, I suppose the qualifier is mostly moot. Also, the fact that the bag is a mouth, potentially leading to a digestive tract seems rather important. Few other living creatures are known to incorporate nondimensional spaces into it's biology and physiology. Seems rather the sort of thing you mention any time the subject in question is brought up. Rather beastly not to, ne?

Comment: Are the terms "rift" and "gate" also interchangeable, with respect to the consequences of placing bags in holes and vice-versa?

Comment: @Air According to the *DMG*, putting a *bag* in a *hole* forever destroys both with its rift, but putting a *hole* in a *bag* forever destroys both *and* sucks into its gate every creature within 10 ft. of the suicide bagger who did it. So, in context, it appears the rift isn't dangerous to those nearby like the gate. I can't say if that rift/gate language is consistent across all kinds of effects, though. I suspect those sorts of linguistic choices are more whimsical than mechanical.

Comment: In practical terms, I suppose I'm mainly curious if "gate" implies the formation of a connection that persists and could be used repeatedly (in either direction?) by PCs or other PC-sized creatures. I've very little experience with the game but it sounds like a potentially entertaining "hack" for PCs lacking another means of getting to that plane.

Comment: @Air I'm pretty sure this has drifted into *Pose it as a question* territory. I don't have the space in comments to discuss the various means of inadvertent planar travel, and whether the *bag/hole//hole/bag* interaction has been codified officially in other products. However, note that the *bag/hole* combo costs 22,500 gp -- quite a bit more than just a *scroll of plane shift* -- and the combo carries with it *substantially* more risk.

Comment: This logic is new to me, backed up by evidence from the DMG which is hard to refute. However, the Portable Hole's mix-and-match of the terms could be some long-unerrata'd error. From the choice of words used (and what they mean literally), it should be clear that extradimensional represents association with another dimension/plane whereas nondimensional indicates that the space does not. Is there no official statement from Wizard designers on the use of this language in Portable Hole?

Comment: @Axoren As the answer's Speculation mentions, I think it's just crossed wires on the developers' parts. That is, there are *no* nondimensional spaces in the *PH*, and, with that in mind, I suspect the term *extradimensional space* was supposed to be used consistently, and somebody forgot and used *nondimensional spaces* a couple of times in the *DMG* accidentally. The alternative is that there's a secret and—given diversity of their uses—wholly *unquantifiable* difference between the two terms… and *that* possibility is largely foiled by the *portable hole*. But, also, your game, your rules.

Answer (score 10):

**I did some research on this for you.**

There are numerous discussions about this around the internet on different forums. I have linked the most relevant here:

- [Giant in the Playground Forum](http://www.giantitp.com/forums/showthread.php?213496-extradimensional-space)
- [Enworld Forum](http://www.enworld.org/forum/showthread.php?67384-Extra-Dimensional-Spaces-NonDimensional-Spaces-Pocket-Dimensional-Space-Yeah)

**What are they saying?**

Pretty much that:

> the rules never make a distinction between the two

and

> It's just two ways of saying the same thing

**Wizards has something to say about it.**

There is also an post on the [Wizards](http://www.wizards.com/default.asp?x=dnd/rg/20051101a) site discussing it. This Wizards post has a very telling sentence:

> These are collectively known as extradimensional spaces, though this is not a defined game term.

It goes on to explain a bit more about these items and some more.

**What can we learn from all this?**

These terms are vague at best. There seems to be no difference between the two terms mechanically. A Bag of Holding is sometimes referred to as being non-dimensional as well as extra-dimensional - this leads to even more confusion. I think you should just make your own judgement call on what the difference is. But it seems there is none.