# Self only teleportation with characters inside extra-dimensional storage

Tags: dnd-3.5e, magic-items, teleportation

Can you teleport with a teleport self only spell if you have the other character inside of an extra-dimensional storage in your possession?

For example a Hound Archon tries to teleport with 4 PC's inside his bag of holding that he has on him, not exceeding the 50 pound limit.

Answer (score 7):

## Yes, that's legit

Creatures and objects in a [*bag of holding*](http://www.systemreferencedocuments.org/resources/systems/pennpaper/dnd35/soveliorsage/magicItemsWI.html#bag-of-holding) (and other similar [extradimensional spaces](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/37845/8610)) are literally *on a different plane* from such a creature employing the teleport effect, so those objects and creatures within the *bag* don't count toward the teleport effect's weight or passenger capacity. The creature using the teleport effect is, essentially, just carrying a (perhaps heavy) door; the creature's not carrying the entire house and all it contains.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can. You're not teleporting people, just the entrance to the space they're in, which you're not teleporting with you anyway.